Data scraping issue using rvest and tidyverse
I am new to data scraping and I am trying to scrape a table from web page (https://vos.oph.fi/cgi-bin/tiedot2.cgi?saaja=1361;tnimi=kust/v08/k05k7s.lis).
I am currently using tidyverse to do this with code (the selectorgadget is used to find the correct node, although I have my doubts whether it is working correctly):
url <- "https://vos.oph.fi/cgi-bin/tiedot2.cgi?saaja=1361;tnimi=kust/v08/k05k7s.lis"
webpage <- read_html(url)
table_code <- html_nodes(webpage, ".table") 
table1<-html_table(table_code , header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
table1

However, the end result is a table with nothing in it (a tibble: 0x0)
What am I doing wrong?

That web page contents is plain text, there is no table in it. Try webpage %>% html_text(). Then parse the text to retrieve the table.

If you check the html source, you should notice that the txt report is in <pre> element which represents preformatted text. And as there happens to be just one pre element, you can safely use "pre" for a selector, get all the text and split it by newlines.
I'm assuming you are only after the main table, for such pre-formatted text reports readr::read_fwf() (fixed width files) can be quite handy.
Let's also assume that report start and row count is fixed and we can just manually select ranges of rows that we'll parse as header and as table body.
library(rvest)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

url_ <- "https://vos.oph.fi/cgi-bin/tiedot2.cgi?saaja=1361;tnimi=kust/v08/k05k7s.lis"

# read lines from <pre> .. </pre> section
report <- 
  read_html(url_) |> 
  html_element("pre") |> 
  html_text() |> 
  read_lines()

# check relevant part
str_view(report)[18:30]
#> [18] │      VALTIONOSUUSPOHJAAN KUULUVAT MENOT
#> [19] │                                             01            02             03             04             Menot yhteensä *)
#> [20] │                                        Palkkaukset     Muut menot  Arvonlisävero       Alv%            euroa   e/oppilas
#> [21] │  
#> [22] │      010  Opetus                         1.206.307        363.051         14.705        4,1        1.584.063       5.194
#> [23] │      020  Majoitus ja kuljetus                   0              0              0        0,0                0           0
#> [24] │      031  Oppilasruokailu                   54.862         57.595         11.856       20,6          124.313         408
#> [25] │      039  Muu oppilashuolto                 51.455         12.692              0        0,0           64.147         210
#> [26] │      061  Sisäinen hallinto                 27.751         19.188          2.249       11,7           49.188         161
#> [27] │      062  Kiinteistöjen ylläpito            31.447        290.850         25.417        8,7          347.714       1.140
#> [28] │      090  Pienet hankkeet                                       0              0        0,0                0           0
#> [29] │                                      -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> [30] │           Yhteensä                       1.371.822        743.376         54.227        7,3        2.169.425       7.113

# process lines that make up a 2-row header, build valid column names
col_names <- 
  report[19:20] |> 
  I() |> 
  read_fwf(show_col_types = FALSE) |> 
  t() |> 
  `colnames<-`(c("h1", "h2")) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(h1 = str_remove(h1, "\\d+"), 
         h2 = str_replace(h2, "\\s{2,}", "|")) |> 
  separate_longer_delim(h2, "|") |> 
  unite(names, c(h1, h2)) |> 
  pull(names) |> 
  janitor::make_clean_names()
glimpse(col_names)
#>  chr [1:6] "palkkaukset" "muut_menot" "arvonlisavero" "alv_percent" ...

# process report body, configure locale for used grouping and decimal marks,
# set column names
report_tbl <- 
  report[22:28] |> 
  I() |> 
  read_fwf(locale = locale("fi", grouping_mark = ".", decimal_mark = ","), show_col_types = FALSE) |> 
  setNames(c("x1", "x2", col_names)) 

Resulting tibble:
report_tbl
#> # A tibble: 7 × 8
#>   x1    x2                     palkkaukset muut_menot arvonlisavero alv_percent
#>   <chr> <chr>                        <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 010   Opetus                     1206307     363051         14705         4.1
#> 2 020   Majoitus ja kuljetus             0          0             0         0  
#> 3 031   Oppilasruokailu              54862      57595         11856        20.6
#> 4 039   Muu oppilashuolto            51455      12692             0         0  
#> 5 061   Sisäinen hallinto            27751      19188          2249        11.7
#> 6 062   Kiinteistöjen ylläpito       31447     290850         25417         8.7
#> 7 090   Pienet hankkeet                 NA          0             0         0  
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: menot_yhteensa_euroa <dbl>,
#> #   menot_yhteensa_e_oppilas <dbl>
glimpse(report_tbl)
#> Rows: 7
#> Columns: 8
#> $ x1                       <chr> "010", "020", "031", "039", "061", "062", "09…
#> $ x2                       <chr> "Opetus", "Majoitus ja kuljetus", "Oppilasruo…
#> $ palkkaukset              <dbl> 1206307, 0, 54862, 51455, 27751, 31447, NA
#> $ muut_menot               <dbl> 363051, 0, 57595, 12692, 19188, 290850, 0
#> $ arvonlisavero            <dbl> 14705, 0, 11856, 0, 2249, 25417, 0
#> $ alv_percent              <dbl> 4.1, 0.0, 20.6, 0.0, 11.7, 8.7, 0.0
#> $ menot_yhteensa_euroa     <dbl> 1584063, 0, 124313, 64147, 49188, 347714, 0
#> $ menot_yhteensa_e_oppilas <dbl> 5194, 0, 408, 210, 161, 1140, 0

Created on 2024-09-01 with reprex v2.1.1
